# How to distribute an object to a hexagonal grid?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I want to create a hexagonal Array (in other name: honeycomb) of this object:

[image]

It is very important: I don't want to "join" the distributed objects, I want to leave them as *dynamic* as possible (so I prefer modifier-like solutions), but I also want blender to treat them as one mesh-object, just like the Array-modifier would do, when I click on the `merge` checkbox. So when I add a Subdivision-modifier to my object it will look like this:

[image]

---

***NOTE:***

The sample object I provided here is a simplified object of the one I'm going to use for this purpose: so the Wireframe-modifier and the Skin-modifier is not an option in my case. Also distributing with a hexagonal grid particle system or duplicate object to vertices of a parent object are not options, since the "final" object won't be "merged" as a single one.

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: 2000th question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an even easier/faster solution than the one @CharlesL provided *(Although some steps are identical)* :

1. Create only 4/6 of the "cell" by using an Array-modifier and an Empty-object rotated by 60°:

   [image]
2. Then add another Array and distribute objects on the *x* direction by the Relative Offset:

   [image]
3. And last but not least, add another Array and distribute the result of the previous modifier on the *y* direction by the Relative Offset `1`:

   [image]

Of course the `merge` option checked in all three of the Array-modifiers.
And the result is a *lighter* and better version of the hexagonal array creation, plus, the result has more beautiful "edges".

Comment: the holes do not seem to be perfectly circular.

Answer (score 9):

Given the shape that you have pictured above, you can do this fairly easily with a couple of array modifiers.

1. Start by creating a sing "cell" of the grid by adding an array modifier to the object. Uncheck *Relative Offset* and check *Object Offset*. Create an empty and rotate and use it for the *Object Offset*. Rotate the empty 60° (make sure that the object's origin is in the same position as the empty):

   [image]

   *Array Modifier Setup*

   [image]

   *Result*
2. Check the *Merge* option and change the distance until all the vertices merge.

   [image]
3. Add another array modifier, and using either *Relative Offset* or another empty (with *Object Offset*), position it at the top left corner of the original object. Set the count to 2 and set the *Merge* options as before:

   [image]

   *Modifier settings*

   [image]

   *Result*
4. Add two more array modifiers to create the grid along the *X* and *Y* axis.

   [image]

   *Modifier settings*

   [image]

   *Result*