# Modelling array of holes into mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm practising how to model my Kitchen radio. On the top of the model it has many holes, I've used subdivision modifier on my mesh. My first attempt was to deactivate the submodifier and make an array of holes, but once I turned on the subdivision modifier again, it was extremely unclean mesh.

So what would be the best way to achieve the holes on top of the mesh?

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Duplicate a 6 vertex circle, extrude inwards, extrude down, fill, then  duplicate along 2 *Array* modifiers,  it will give you a grid of holes. Then join to the rest of the topology. You can even bake a normal map if you don't want to keep too many faces.

[image]

Also, don't forget to add edge loops in order to sharp your edges:

[image]

Comment: I got a little confused, I add the circle and followed your instructions making the circle and array modifier. But in your image, there is a flat mesh connecting to the circle., so this is what confused me. 

https://ibb.co/nMxx8s8

Comment: yes so move the border and scale them on the X or Y axis (S + X + 0) to make them flat and build a square around your circle. Also don't forget to enable the Merge and First Last options of your Arrays

Comment: Ok thanks for that, I managed to understand. The only intimidating part in joining it to the rest of the mesh.

https://ibb.co/WPxryQk

Thank you.

Comment: also, see my edit, add edge loops in order to sharp your edges

Comment: I would like to add another method as well. But not too sure if one method is better than the other. Here is a screen shot. 
https://ibb.co/w0kFkHX

Comment: yes there are a lot of ways, it also depends on your needs, will you have to make some close-up shots, etc...