# Making little holes in mesh

Tags: modifiers

I'm quite the beginner with blender (just finished the donut) and I wanted to make a 3D replica of a radio that I have, but I have no idea how to make the little holes properly that it has in it.I assume the best way to make it is with the boolean modifier but it takes my pc like 30 seconds to calculate. Is there a better way to do this?

[image: outcome of using boolean operator]

These are my modifier settings:

[image]

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/BjYd24Q) i used these settings

Comment: @batFINGER already tried boolean and that didnt work properly, maybe the first solution in that post could work but I already got an answer to my problem thanks to moonboots

Comment: I'd use a honeycomb object for that. In Preferences > Add-ons, search for 'extra' and check the Add Mesh: Extra objects entry.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fake holes with normal or bump maps, but if you want to create real holes, create a plane, subdivide, select all except the borders:

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel the vertices (go into the *Operator* box to select *Vertices*):

[image]

If you want more than 4 vertex holes, increase the amount of *Segments* and choose *Shape > 1* to make them round:

[image]

In *Face Selection* mode, select one face and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> > *Polygon Sides* to select all the similar faces:

[image]

If you ever change the holes size, choose *Transform Pivot Point > Individual Origins*. When you're good, press <kbd>i</kbd> twice to inset each face:

[image]

Extrude down a little bit, then again twice, then give it a *Subdivision Surface* and *Shade Smooth*:

[image]